# How can std::thread::JoinHandle::join catch panics?

Tags: rust

The code below compiles only if `dyn Fn` is `UnwindSafe + RefUnwindSafe`, because `panic::catch_unwind` requires it to be able to catch the panic.

```
use std::panic;
use std::panic::{UnwindSafe, RefUnwindSafe};

fn launch_closure(f: Box<dyn Fn() +  UnwindSafe + RefUnwindSafe>) {
    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        f();
    });    
}
```

However, [std::thread::JoinHandle::join](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) function is able to catch the panic even if the thread closure is not `UnwindSafe + RefUnwindSafe`:

> If the child thread panics, Err is returned with the parameter given
> to panic!.

How?

I'd like to be able to know if my closure panicked, but `UnwindSafe + RefUnwindSafe` is too restrictive, I cannot use `CondVar` for example.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1eaf7a6900e0fec6aae4bfb9aa24d2b7)

Comment: `RefUnwindSafe` is only required because you’re not moving `f` into the closure.  [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b2cc01eed9ccb5b9c0aeec128a61d795)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`thread::spawn` [wraps the closure in an `AssertUnwindSafe`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b/library/std/src/thread/mod.rs#L480-L482) to tell the compiler that it *knows* that the given closure is unwind-safe:

> ```
> let try_result = panic::catch_unwind(panic::AssertUnwindSafe(|| {
>     crate::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace(f)
> }));
> ```

So, what is unwind safety and how can `thread::spawn` make that assertion?

From the documentation for [`UnwindSafe`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/trait.UnwindSafe.html):

> In Rust a function can “return” early if it either panics or calls a function which transitively panics. This sort of control flow is not always anticipated, and has the possibility of causing subtle bugs through a combination of two critical components:
>
> 1. A data structure is in a temporarily invalid state when the thread panics.
> 2. This broken invariant is then later observed.

A type is *not* unwind safe if both of these can be true.

Types like `Mutex` and `RwLock` **are** unwind safe because they use poisoning to protect you from broken invariants. If a panic occurs in another thread that has a lock on a `Mutex` then it becomes poisoned and you must explicitly call `PoisonError::into_inner` to access the possibly-inconsistent data. If you cause a bug by making assumptions about a poisoned mutex, then that's your own responsibility and the Rust type system can't help you there.

Mutable references and non-sharable types with interior mutability like `RefCell` **are not** unwind safe because they don't offer such protection. However, they are also not `Sync`, so you can't get into a situation where you use them after another thread has panicked while holding a reference.

The final piece of the puzzle is that `thread::spawn` creates a new thread stack. That means it can guarantee that the closure is called first in the stack so nothing *in the same thread as the closure* can access its environment after a panic is caught.

While `thread::spawn` can't guarantee that the closure is unwind safe in the general case, it knows that:

1. The closure is `Send` (by its own bounds), so it cannot contain references to non-`Sync` types.
2. The non-unwind safe types in `std` (mutable references and cell types) are also not `Sync`, which means nothing can access a non-unwind safe type from *outside* the thread
3. Nothing in the *same* thread as the call to the closure can access its environment after the panic is caught.

So it is safe for the closure to be unwound because there is no possibility of broken invariants being unintentionally observed after a panic.

It is of course possible for a closure to make use of a user-defined type that is not unwind safe but *is* `Sync`, in which case this assumption would turn out to be incorrect. However, this would require `unsafe` code either from a third party crate or by the same author as the closure itself. It is always the responsibility of the author of `unsafe` code to ensure memory safety. It is not sound for a type to be `Sync` if a panic in another thread could cause UB. It is up to the author to decide if logical bugs are acceptable, but memory unsafety never is.

---

So... can you use the same trick in your code? Unfortunately, you probably cannot. Since you don't have control over the caller of `launch_closure`, you can't make the guarantee that a panic won't cause invalid state to be observed by callers in the same thread.